# HTML 5 video js update source and play once loaded

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I am trying to change the source of a HTML 5 video using Video.js.

Source is changing and I can click play and it'll play the video, but I need video to play on an event. Specifically the `loadedalldata` event.

I've read the [api documentation](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api.md) and it suggest, that what I've done should work (From my understanding.).

Javascript:

```
var player = _V_('video'),
    video = [{
        "type": "video\/mp4",
        "src": "http:\/\/mabuse.dev\/assets\/videos\/testVideo.mp4"
    }, {
        "type": "video\/webm",
        "src": "http:\/\/mabuse.dev\/assets\/videos\/testVideo.webm"
    }, {
        "type": "video\/ogg",
        "src": "http:\/\/mabuse.dev\/assets\/videos\/testVideo.ogv"
    }, {
        "type": "video\/flv",
        "src": "http:\/\/mabuse.dev\/assets\/videos\/testVideo.flv"
    }];

/* Add sources to new player */
player.src(video);

/* Remove loader & play video once loaded */
player.on("loadedalldata", function(){
    console.log('test');
    //app.player.play();
});
```

HTML:

```
<video class="video-js" id="video" controls preload="none" width="572" height="356" data-setup="{}"></video>
```

Comment: It's just a rough guessing, but try to change the string to this:
`{ "type": "video/mp4","src": "http://mabuse.dev/assets/videos/testVideo.mp4" }`

The video player might not understand the URL you're passing to it...

Comment: By the way, I would also bind the event before setting the `src`.

Answer (score 1):

Try listening to a similar event that is dispatched directly from the video element.

```
document.querySelector("#video").addEventListener("canplaythrough", onLoaded)
```